# Asp Mvc shortens urls with default parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a route setup like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "Dashboard/{controller}/{departmentType}/{action}/{year}/{month}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Kpi",
        departmentType = DepartmentType.Ops,
        action = "Details",
        year = DateTime.Today.Year,
        month = DateTime.Today.Month
    });
```

In the views, when I use `Url.Action`, Mvc generates the following routes:

- departmentType.Ops: `<a href="/dashboard" class="active">OPS</a>`
- departmentType.Bps: `<a href="/dashboard/kpi/bps" class="active">BPS</a>`

Mvc uses the default route for my OPS department, not filling in the `{controller}` and `{departmentType}`parameters defined in my routings. This is making the JavaScript from a plugin fail to make the correct `a`-tag active.

Is there a way to configure Mvc to always fill in all parameters when generating a route?

**Edit: By request the `Url.Action`-methods**

```
<a href='@Url.Action("details", "kpi", RouteValues(DepartmentType.Ops))'>OPS</a>
<a href='@Url.Action("details", "kpi", RouteValues(DepartmentType.BPS))'>BPS</a>

@functions
{
    object RouteValues(DepartmentType dt)
    {
        return new
        {
            DepartmentType = dt,
            year = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["year"],
            month = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["month"]
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the overload that lets you specify the protocol and seeing what it generates?

Comment: Worth a shot but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Show your exact code of those `Url.Action` please.

Comment: Not sure how many other routes you defined, the most straight forward way is to use `Url.RouteUrl` instead